# Inserting or adding a string to a database table using linq to SQL and EF6?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm trying to learn LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework 6. Just trying to add strings to a database table.

Here is what I've got for now:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        using (ResponsesEntities db = new ResponsesEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                Respons res = new Respons();
                res.ExtSerial = "ASDF1234";
                res.Date = "2015-05-01";
                res.FileName = @"C:\tae.XML";
                res.ResponseDescription = "OK";

                db.Responses.Add(res);

                Console.WriteLine("Inserted!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TAE! Error");                    
            }
        }
```

It runs but it won't add the strings to the table.

Comment: Be aware: Linq-to-SQL is a **separate**, different ORM than Entity Framework. It was designed by the C# team as a "proof-of-concept" of what Linq can do. EF was designed and built by the data team at Microsoft - different beast. You cannot use both at the same time - and Linq-to-SQL is really considered dead-end technology, while EF is the current (and future) Microsoft ORM offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only adding the object to the **in-memory** store - you need to **persist** your changes back to the database!

```
 db.Responses.Add(res);
 db.SaveChanges();   // this will write the changes to the database
```

Comment: Oh no, how ignorant of me. Thank you @marc_s. You have my thanks.